# Regex string inside 2 special characters without space

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a RegEx for `preg_match_all` in [php](/questions/tagged/php) to match a string inside 2 `$` symbols, like `$abc$` but only if it doesn't have a space, for example, I don't need to match `$ab c$`.

I wrote this regex `/[\$]\S(.*)[\$]/U` and some variations but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

Your regex: `[\$]\S(.*)[\$]`

- `[\$]` - No point in escaping `$` inside `[]` because it's already interpreted as the literal character. No point putting `\$` inside `[]` because `\$` is the escaped version. Just use one or the other `[$]` or `\$`.
- `\S(.*)` Matches any non-whitespace character (once), followed by any character (except `\n`) any number of times

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7bAmdX/1)

```
\$\S+\$
```

- `\$` Match `$` literally
- `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character one or more times
- `\$` Match `$` literally

#### Usage

```
$re = '/\$\S+\$/';
$str = '$abc$
$ab c$';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will suit your needs.

https://regex101.com/r/WgUwh9/1

```
\$([a-zA-Z]*)\$
```

It will match a-Z of any lenght without space between two `$`